# How can i merge multiple repository into a single repository?

Tags: git, github

All repos are connected to one place, but when I want to develop and push only one repo, I don't want to push it to the repo it is connected to.

as an example we have a project named "xyzSystem"

Let this be 3 separate subprojects of our main project. (purely as an example) A-project `js-html` ,
Let's say they use B-project `.NET`, C-project other language.

and when developing in any of these projects, the remote url

```
username/xyzSystem/A-project.git

username/xyzSystem/B-project.git

username/xyzSystem/C-project.git
```

Doing it this way will avoid complexity. I don't know if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a GitHub project?
https://github.com/new/project

A project is kind of like a folder where the subproject (In this case A B and C) are different files/repos (not really files but a part of a bigger folder) but the are hosted under one project.

For example you are doing a project for a college and it needs 3 parts you would use a project and the subproject/repos will be the 3 parts and you can present all of them in the same project instead of searching for 3 separate repos.

Comment: You suggest that I create a subfolder from a repository (I hope I didn't misunderstand). I think this will make changes for all repositories in the subfolder when the pull is pushed (branches and commits). This is not exactly what I want.

Comment: I did not mean to put them as folders. (unless you wanted to in that case it is your choice because each dev arranges their work in their own way) I was just letting you know that is an option and it should fit your needs (as long as I understand it correctly). And not many know about this feature so when I talked about this feature it might let other people find different uses for it.